# Can't resize iFrame

Tags: html, css

The iFrame or wrapper div will not change size, whatever i try:

The Output:
[image: output]

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CV.css">
<title>
George's CV
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div className="phone" style="height: 737px; width: 654px">
        <div className="container" style="height: 536px; width: 350px">
            <iframe src="http://foodsharing-production.herokuapp.com"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.phone{
    margin:auto;
    height: 737px;
    width: 654px;
    background-image: url("/imgs/phone.png");
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
}
.container {
    position: fixed;
    left:0; right:0;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 536px;
    width: 350px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
 }
```

feel like i might be missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Please share with us some example of what this is supposed to look like when working correctly.

Comment: Add `width/height` attributes to iframe.

Comment: i've added an example of what it currently looks like, if i could get it to display the way i wanted then there wouldn't be an issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to have inline and external styles at the same time, just use one or the other, ideally external. You need to target the `iframe` element to affect it with your styles. I've also made it's width responsive with the `max-width: 100%` because I think it might come in handy:

```css
.phone {
  margin:auto;
  height: 737px;
  width: 654px;
  background-image: url("/imgs/phone.png");
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 536px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}

iframe {
  width: 500px; /* adjust to your needs */
  max-width: 100%; /* to make it responsive */
}
```

```html
<div className="phone">
  <div className="container">
    <iframe src="http://foodsharing-production.herokuapp.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: added the inline styles cus the external ones were being ignored haha

Answer (score 2):

Change the width on the iframe itself. E.g.

```
<div className="phone">
  <div className="container">
    <iframe width="600px" src="http://foodsharing-production.herokuapp.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also set this in the CSS:

```
iframe {
  width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should increase its size with CSS like that

```
iframe {
  width:350px;
  height:536px;
}
```